# Derivative of a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I tried to take the derivative the function, but I can't find my mistake:

```
syms x
A = -1.6*x^2+18.7*x+3.4
```

This returns `(187*x)/10 - (8*x^2)/5 + 17/5`.

Then, `diff(A)` yields `187/10 - (16*x)/5`.

Comment: What answer did you expect?

Comment: Are you expecting symbolic math to give your results in floating point?

Answer (score 2):

There is no mistake here. The derivative of a second degree polynomial is a first degree polynomial... hence the variable `x` is still present in the result and you cannot evaluate it numerically unless you give a value to `x`:

```
vpa(subs(diff(A),x,4)) % evaluates the derivative for X=4, yields 5.9
```

If you want to reduce your function to a scalar value, a second order derivative must be taken:

```
vpa(diff(A,2)) % this returns: -3.2
```

Finally, if you just feel that the numerical parts of the result are "messy" and should be evaluated, you can call the [vpa function](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) on the derivative:

```
vpa(diff(A)) % this returns: 18.7 - 3.2*x
```